# How to format the layout of email notifications in Console Application using C#

Tags: c#, console-application

For starters, I have reviewed suggested questions that are considered similar but none addresses my current issue.

I have written a console app that monitors several applications residing in our DMZ servers (five in all for now) and notify users four times a day whether or not any or all of the apps are UP or DOWN.

Currently, when you run the app, it works by simply indicating in email Subject whether the apps are down or up.

Below is the current working email functionally:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace showserverstatus
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
           int result = 0;
            foreach (string site in args)
            {
                if (!ServerStatusBy(site))
                {
                    result++;
                }
            }

            return result;

        }

        static bool ServerStatusBy(string site)
        {
            Ping pingSender = new();
            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(site, 10000);
            if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                SendEmail($"{site} DOWN", $"Ping {site}");
                return false;
            }
            SendEmail($"{site} UP", $@"Ping {site}");

            return true;
        }
        public static void SendEmail(string subject, string body)
        {
            using MailMessage mm = new(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"], "myemail@gmail.com");
            mm.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
            mm.CC.Add("myother@att.net");
            mm.Subject = subject;
            mm.Body = body;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;

            SmtpClient smtp = new()
            {
                Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"],
                Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]),
                EnableSsl = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]),
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
            smtp.Send(mm);
            Console.WriteLine("Email sent.");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

The challenge currently is how to format the layout of the email sent to our executives so that the email subject reads:
Status Of Applications on DMZ Server

Email body reads:
Please find the status of the DMZ servers below:
Then followed by the listings of the applications, one application per one line.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated,

Comment: By replacing `$"{site} UP", $@"Ping {site}"` with the strings you actually want?

Comment: `Then followed by the listings of the applications, one application per one line.` Use `StringBuilder` or string concatenation to build the string you want. Then add that to the body.

Comment: Or create a tokensizable html template with handlebars or something, or just use SendGrid ect, though might be a bit overkill for you

Comment: using SendGrid might be a little bit of an overkill, don't you think?

I do really appreciate the comment though.

Comment: Jeremy, if I replace Up with string, which is DMZ Server Status which is the Subject, where do I fit in the UP and DOWN?

This question might be too elementary but I would appreciate some clarifications.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the ping results and send a single email after all the sites have been pinged:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var siteToStatus = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var site in args) {
        var reply = new Ping().Send(site, 10000);
        siteToStatus[site] = (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? "UP" : "DOWN";
    }
    var subject = "Status Of Applications on DMZ Server";
    var body = "Please find the status of the DMZ servers below:";
    foreach (var kvp in siteToStatus) {
        body += $"{Environment.NewLine}{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}"; // e.g. "google.com: UP"
    }
    SendEmail(subject, body);
}
```

Comment: Hi Spencer,

I think you are on to something good here. The question is, does your solution replace the ServerStatusBy(...) method?

Can you please put it where it needs to be so I don't confuse things?

Thanks a lot bro

Wait, looking at it further, I think that's where it goes.

Comment: @Kenny It replaces `Main`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Kenny I'm afraid I don't know enough about how the `Ping` class works to help you there.